# Что не так?

Tags: лингвистика

Свое современное название улица обрела в 1929 году в честь композитора, пианиста, основателя Санкт-Петербургской консерватории, ее директора и профессора Антона Григорьевича Рубинштейна (1829-1894), жившего на улице Рубинштейна.

Answer (score 1):

Не так то, что получается, профессор Антон Григорьевич Рубинштейн (1829-1894), жил на улице Рубинштейна. Надо "Свое современное название улица такая-то обрела в 1929 году в честь композитора, пианиста, основателя Санкт-Петербургской консерватории, ее директора и профессора Антона Григорьевича Рубинштейна (1829-1894), жившего на этой улице"